# Unordered list with reset.css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have included `reset.css` which is pretty common for most websites that use, on one of the page in my website I have a unordered list and I have a problem knowing what were their defaults.

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>First item</li>
            <li>Second item</li>
            <li>Third item</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Like this:

- Item 1
  - First item
  - Second item
  - Third item
- Item 2
- Item 3

Can I have the defaults which I can set in CSS (when including `reset.css`). I don't want to remove `ul` and `li` from the `reset.css` since I have used styling for an unordered list on different pages, so if I remove it, it would affect the whole website.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of the reset stylesheet is to make all the browsers behave the same with respect to HTML elements. That means there is no single set of styles that apply to those elements across the various browsers. So "defaults" is kind of a meaningless term here.'

The `<li>` especially is subject to wildly different renderings. Your only hope, if you really really really want to go through with it, is to look at the computed styles for each element on each browser and try to do something with those values, but I don't see this as being of much value.